# Setting up a VPN server for LAN access over the internet using OpenVPN in linux

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, vpn, openvpn

I want to set up a LAN over the internet VPN server to be able to access my computer, play games with my friends, etc...
I have little knowledge about networking.
But I have came across a guide for this:

https://codentium.com/using-openvpn-to-play-old-games-with-your-friends.html

Everything was going smoothly, until I got an error after starting the service. Here's the error:

"journalctl -xe" output:

```
-- Unit openvpn.games.service has begun starting up.
Nov 03 16:54:56 vm9707380586.bitcommand.com openvpn.games[2418]:  * Starting virtual private network daemon
Nov 03 16:54:56 vm9707380586.bitcommand.com ovpn-games[2432]: Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in /etc/openvpn/games.conf: push (2.4.4)

Nov 03 16:54:56 vm9707380586.bitcommand.com ovpn-games[2432]: Use --help for more information.
Nov 03 16:54:56 vm9707380586.bitcommand.com openvpn.games[2418]:    ...fail!
Nov 03 16:54:56 vm9707380586.bitcommand.com systemd[1]: openvpn.games.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 03 16:54:56 vm9707380586.bitcommand.com systemd[1]: openvpn.games.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 03 16:54:56 vm9707380586.bitcommand.com systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Openvpn VPN service.
-- Subject: Unit openvpn.games.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit openvpn.games.service has failed.
```

After changing `push 10.42.42.0 255.255.255.0` to `push "10.42.42.0 255.255.255.0"`, I still get another error.

```
-- Unit openvpn.games.service has begun starting up.
Nov 03 14:21:25 vm9707380586.bitcommand.com openvpn.games[1446]:  * Starting virtual private network daemon
Nov 03 14:21:25 vm9707380586.bitcommand.com ovpn-games[1461]: Options error: ifconfig parms 'pool-persist' and 'games-ips.txt' must be valid addresses
Nov 03 14:21:25 vm9707380586.bitcommand.com ovpn-games[1461]: Use --help for more information.
Nov 03 14:21:25 vm9707380586.bitcommand.com openvpn.games[1446]:    ...fail!
Nov 03 14:21:25 vm9707380586.bitcommand.com systemd[1]: openvpn.games.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 03 14:21:25 vm9707380586.bitcommand.com systemd[1]: openvpn.games.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 03 14:21:25 vm9707380586.bitcommand.com systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Openvpn VPN service.
-- Subject: Unit openvpn.games.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit openvpn.games.service has failed.
```

My VPS operating system: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.

I did the configurations completely according to the website.

I couldn't find a solution. Any idea how to fix it??

**Edit 1:**

Here is my config file (/etc/openvpn/games.conf):

```
ca certs/keys/ca.crt
cert certs/keys/games.crt
key certs/keys/games.key
dh certs/keys/dh2048.pem

port 1194
proto udp
proto udp6
dev tap

user nobody
group nobody

server 10.42.42.0 255.255.255.0
client-to-client
push "route 10.42.42.0 255.255.255.0"
push 10.42.42.0 255.255.255.0
push "route-metric 512"
push "route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0"
topology subnet

persist-key
ifconfig pool-persist games-ips.txt

keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo

status /var/log/openvpn/games-status.log
log /var/log/openvpn/games.log
verb 4
```

I get this error after trying out this command:

> openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/games.conf

```
Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in /etc/openvpn/games.conf:15: push (2.4.4)
Use --help for more information.
```

I suspected that it's the double quotations that are missing after push command so I changed `push 10.42.42.0 255.255.255.0` to `push "10.42.42.0 255.255.255.0"`, but I still get another error:

```
Options error: ifconfig parms 'pool-persist' and 'games-ips.txt' must be valid addresses
Use --help for more information.
```

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be bad syntax in your configuration file. Without actually seeing the configuration file it would be difficult to say exactly what the problem is.

You may find more verbose errors by running the openvpn process in the foreground with the below command.

`openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/games.conf`

EDIT:

After reviewing the output of `openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/games.conf` it looks like the issue is on line 23. The correct syntax is `ifconfig-pool-persist games-ips.txt`.

Comment: I put a source up there to check it out. The configurations were all according to there.
However, I put the configurations here too.
Seems like the configurations are wrong or something.
What I want to accomplish is LAN over Internet, so any information about how to work this up would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for that! I updated the answer, let me know if this works out for you.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I spotted some problems and fixed them. Currently I am continuing the guide. There might be some other frustrating issues ahead which I'll be happy to share with you and receive your response.